# Recorrer un datagridview y capturar datos específicos por definición o caracteres

Tags: vb.net

[image: Recorrer un datagridview y capturar datos específicos por definición o caracteres]
Buenos días, maestros de la comunidad, necesito su ayuda. Al usar el siguiente código recorro el  DataGridView3 y obtengo el resultado mostrado en el  ListBox2, pero esta información está incompleta, pues no encuentro la forma de capturar los 4 caracteres que siempre le seguirán en la siguiente celda mas abajo, una vez que el capture los 25 anteriores que componen el dato "Número de TC:111112222222".  Este es el código:

```
*Dim maestro As String
        'Dim lista1_MLC As String
        For Each row1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView3.Rows
            maestro = row1.Cells(5).Value
            '--------------------------
            TextBox12.Text = maestro
            Dim contar As Integer = 0
            '   For Each item As Char In TextBox12.Text
            For Each item As Char In TextBox12.Text
                If item = " "c Then
                    Continue For
                End If
                contar += 1
                             
                If contar = 25 Then
'   Aquí el contador no debe ser menor de 25 o capturara otras informaciones no deseada.
                    ListBox2.Items.Add(auditora)
                    If contar = 6 Then
                        ListBox2.Items.Add(auditora)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next*
```

---

El resultado que necesito es el siguiente:
"Número de TC: 1111-1222-2222-2222"
"Producto: 195.00"
"Numero de operación: 118"

Answer (score 0):

la pregunta esta algo enredada, si entiendo bien, lo que necesitas es:

1. Que tome el valor de la primera fila de la columna operaciones y le anexe el  valor de la segunda fila de la columna operaciones, no nos preocupemos por el formato, por ahora.
2. Tomar el texto "Producto:" y anexarle un valor que esta en la tercera fila de la columna Operaciones.
3. Tomar el texto "Numero de operacion:" y anexarle un valor que esta en la primera fila de la columna Column5
4. Luego unir estas tres cosas y formar el texto:
   "Numero de TC:1111122222222222 Producto:195.00 Numero de operacion:118" sigamos sin preocuparnos por el formato
5. Ignorar la fila 4
6. Volver a iniciar el proceso en la fila 5 hasta terminar los datos de DataGridView3
   Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Asi es mi hermano, como puedo resolver este problema???..